# Chemfig Electron Pair + Charge + Branch Help

Tags: chemfig

I need help figuring out how to branch from an atom with an electron pair and charge. The `\charge` command doesn't seem to allow any branching. `\Lewis` won't work as this is no longer supported by `chemfig`.

Here is my code (invisible arrow is for alignment purposes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}

\setcharge{shortcuts}
\schemestart[][west]
    \chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]\charge{90=\: , -90=\:}{O}H} \arrow{0}[,0]\+ \arrow{0}[,0]\ \chemfig{Cl-[:30]Zn-[:-30]Cl} \arrow{<=>} \arrow{0}[,0]\ \chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]{\chemabove[0pt]{\charge{90=\:}{O}}{\pch}}-[:30]ZnCl} 
\schemestop
\\[2\baselineskip]

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

This is the output I want:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{\charge{90=\: , -90=\:}{O}H(-[:150]-[:-150])}
\+
\chemfig{Cl-[:30]Zn-[:-30]Cl}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){<=>}
\chemfig{\charge{90=\: , 90:5pt=\scriptsize $ + $}{O}(-[:150]-[:-150])(-[6]H)-[:30]ZnCl}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! \scriptsize seems to work perfectly with this

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to start with the oxygen atom and add the 3 bonds -- which are between (...). Electrons and charge can be added using \charge or using a combination of \charge and \chemabove, as shown.

```
\documentclass[margin={2mm 2mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}    

\chemfig{\chemabove{\charge{90=\:}{O}}{^+}(-[:150]-[:210])(-[6]H)(-[:30]ZnCl)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Inserting H in parentheses was the first thing I tried, because that's how you'd normally create a branch. I must have somehow screwed it up the first time I tried it. Thank you for sharing your solution!